# How can i make a look ahead that ignores a subset?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to isolate some fashion sizes in a string into two individual datapoints.

Ie. if i get XXS/XS i want to get "XXS" isolated and then with a second regex get "XS".

For that i have just used group 1 on

`([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

for the first size and

`(?:[^A-Za-z0-9()]+([A-Za-z0-9]+))`

to grab the second size

However i have come into some new weird combinations being a value:

S1 - XXS/XS-S/M

How would i go about ensuring that my regex in this case grabs **XXS/XS** as **the first value** and **S/M** as **the second value**, while also ensuring that i also get **XXS** as **the first value** and **XS** as **the second value** if the string was simply "XXS/XS" OR 40 and 42 with "40-42"?

Simply can't figure out the best way to do this - hope some bright minds know a great way to do so! I can system wise "only" support one regex for getting the first value and a second regex for getting the secondary value. My system only catches group 1.

My code is based around python, so usually use pythex.org to validate that it works in python.

Comment: Meybe `re.findall(r'([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)[/-]([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)', text, re.I)` will work?

Comment: Or, `re.findall(r'((?:[a-z]+|\d+)(?:[/-](?:[a-z]+|\d+))?)[/-]((?:[a-z]+|\d+)(?:[/-](?:[a-z]+|\d+))?)', text, re.I)`? ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MLVcW0/1)) Note that the matches you need are actually in Group 1 and Group 2. Is it a requirement to have two different patterns?

Comment: I grab only group 1 always - however i can have two different regex'es for each of the results. 

Currently testing out if switching to regex instead of re causes any issues

Comment: Using `regex` instead of `re` does not cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use

```py
(?i)([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)[/-]([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MLVcW0/2).

Note the regex above contains two capturing groups that hold your necessary values.

If you need to get Group 1 *always*, then you need to simply remove the unnecessary pair of parentheses from the regex above and keep just a single capturing group.

*Details*

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline modifier option
- `([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)` - one or more alphanumeric chars, and then an optional occurrence of `/` or `-` followed with one or more alphanumeric chars
- `[/-]` - a `/` or `-`
- `([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)` - Group 2: (same as the first group pattern).

Comment: Thanks! This works within current bounds! I can just do a non capturing first for the second value!

Thanks to everybody else as well!

Comment: Quick follow-up question.

How could i use the same to check for a size "XS" or "42" - the current would only capture a size with two values now

Comment: @SteffenMandrup That's a bit hard to implement with the same capturing logic without PyPi regex module, it will be like [`([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)[/-]([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)|^[a-z\d]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/MLVcW0/4). Maybe `(?:^.*?([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)[/-])?([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)|^[a-z\d]+$` would work for you (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MLVcW0/5)).

Comment: I have the option of doing two regex.

Could i somehow isolate the first "size" from the example you gave and then use another regex to do a new group 1 to grab the second ones? 

Important thing for the system is just that i always use group 1 for the result - else i won't be able to index it properly

Comment: Hmm in the first part, it is actually ok to match "S1 - XXS/XS" as a result instead of just "XXS/XS". I have a follow-up process where i map it correctly anyway. Important part is just that i can split the individual sizes up correctly